# get differ by even odd row and combine with other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get differ between even and odd row, then add odd row ts values as well.

Current implementation do differ correctly, but missed the odd row ts values.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['04-21 10:45:21.718'],
    ['04-21 10:45:22.718'],
    ['04-21 10:45:24.718'],
    ['04-21 10:45:28.718'],
    ['04-21 10:45:32.718'],
    ['04-21 10:45:38.718']
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format="%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['ts'].values[1::2] - df['ts'].values[::2],columns=['delta'])
df2['delta'] = df2['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
print(df2)
```

Current output:

```
                   ts
0 1900-04-21 10:45:21.718
1 1900-04-21 10:45:22.718
2 1900-04-21 10:45:24.718
3 1900-04-21 10:45:28.718
4 1900-04-21 10:45:32.718
5 1900-04-21 10:45:38.718
   delta
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    6.0
```

Expected output:

```
                       ts  delta
1 1900-04-21 10:45:22.718    1.0
2 1900-04-21 10:45:28.718    4.0
3 1900-04-21 10:45:38.718    6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df2 = df.assign(delta=df['ts'].diff().dt.total_seconds()).iloc[1::2]
```

Output:

```
                       ts  delta
1 1900-04-21 10:45:22.718    1.0
3 1900-04-21 10:45:28.718    4.0
5 1900-04-21 10:45:38.718    6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `groupby()`

```
df.groupby(df.index//2)['ts'].agg(ts = 'first',delta = lambda x: (x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0]).total_seconds())
```

Output:

```
                       ts  delta
0 1900-04-21 10:45:21.718    1.0
1 1900-04-21 10:45:24.718    4.0
2 1900-04-21 10:45:32.718    6.0
```